# The problem of using {}.fromkey(['k1','k2'],[]) and {'k1':[],'k2':[]}

Tags: python-3.x

```
list1 = [99,55]
dict1 = {'k1':[],'k2':[]}

for num in list1:
    if num > 77:
        dict1['k1'].append(num)
    else:
        dict1['k2'].append(num)
print(dict1)
```

---

> > > {'k1':[99],'k2':[55]}

---

But when I replaced dict1 = {'k1':[],'k2':[]} to  {}.fromkeys(['k1','k2'],[]) , the result became {'k1': [99, 55], 'k2': [99, 55]}

why this happens? I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are passing the same list object to both keys. This is the same situation as when you create an alias for a variable:

```
a = []
b = a

a.append(55)
b.append(99)

print(b)
```

prints `[55, 99]` because it is the same list instance.

If you want to make it more concise from a list of keys to initialize with empty list, you can do this:

```
dict1 = {k: [] for k in ('k1', 'k2')}
```

This will create a new list instance for every key.

Alternatively, you can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict



list1 = [99,55]
dict1 = defaultdict(list)

for num in list1:
    if num > 77:
        dict1['k1'].append(num)
    else:
        dict1['k2'].append(num)
print(dict1)
```

Also works.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! I got it!

Comment: @ugowuTEI Then you can accept & upvote the answer to make clear that this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The fromKeys() can also be supplied with a mutable object as the default value.
if we append value in the original list, the append takes place in all the values of keys.
example:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['SALIO']
dict1 = dict.fromkeys(list1, list2)
print(dict1)
```

output:

```
{'a': ['SALIO'], 'b': ['SALIO'], 'c': ['SALIO'], 'd': ['SALIO']}
```

then you can use this:

```
list1 = ['k1', 'k2']
dict1 = {'k1':[],'k2':[]}
list2 =[99,55]
for num in list2:
    if num > 77:
        a = ['k1']
        dict1 = dict.fromkeys(a, [num])   
    else:
        b = ['k2']
        dict2 = dict.fromkeys(b,[num] )
res = {**dict1, **dict2}
print(res)
```

output:

```
{'k1': [99], 'k2': [55]}
```

You can also use the python code to merge dict code:
this function:

```
def Merge(dict1, dict2):
    return(dict2.update(dict1))
```

then:

```
print(Merge(dict1, dict2)) #This return None

print(dict2) # changes made in dict2
```